# Using composer to download php fuel

Tags: php, composer-php, fuelphp

I'm trying to create a `composer.json` that downloads a specific version of fuel. It's very simple at the moment:

```
{
    "require": {
      "fuel/fuel": "dev-1.7/master"
    }
}
```

but this fails to install, because nothing listed on packagist [here](https://packagist.org/packages/fuel/fuel) has all dependencies satisfied. I've tried 1.6, 1.7, 1.8.

Am I misunderstanding something? Why can I not download fuel with composer?

EDIT: For clarity, I'm not trying to create an entirely new project, but instead to just download fule library inside an existing project. @gellu showed me how to manually add the repositories not on packagist, and by depending on `fuel/core` (instead of fuel itself, which downloads documentation,examples,and many other things I don't need), I was able to download just the library as I wanted

Comment: Does composer work with other packages on your side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually adding all repositories will help:

```
{
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "fuel/auth",
            "type": "fuel-package",
            "version": "1.7.2",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/auth/archive/1.7/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/auth.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "1.8/develop"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "fuel/email",
            "type": "fuel-package",
            "version": "1.7.2",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/email/archive/1.7/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/email.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "1.8/develop"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "fuel/oil",
            "type": "fuel-package",
            "version": "1.7.2",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/oil/archive/1.7/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/oil.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "1.8/develop"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "fuel/orm",
            "type": "fuel-package",
            "version": "1.7.2",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/orm/archive/1.7/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/orm.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "1.8/develop"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "fuel/parser",
            "type": "fuel-package",
            "version": "1.7.2",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/parser/archive/1.7/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/parser.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "1.8/develop"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "fuel/core",
            "type": "fuel-package",
            "version": "1.7.2",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/core/archive/1.7/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/core.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "1.8/develop"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "fuel/docs",
            "type": "fuel-package",
            "version": "1.7.2",
            "dist": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/docs/archive/1.7/master.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/fuel/docs.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "1.8/develop"
            }
        }
    }
],

"require": {
    "fuel/fuel": "dev-1.7/master"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't install Fuel either by a simple require command; however I did manage to install with composer successfully by executing the following command:

```
composer create-project fuel/fuel:dev-1.8/develop --prefer-source
```

I hope it works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install 1.7/master:

```
$ composer create-project fuel/fuel:dev-1.7/master ProjectName
```

If you want to install 1.8/develop:

```
$ composer create-project fuel/fuel:dev-1.8/develop --prefer-source ProjectName
```